# Queue algorithm to retrieve not shown

Tags: sql, algorithm, queue

I have a db which contains french words and want to show them without repetition. I don't want to retrieve all of them and put into an array because I think this will be difficult and not optimized if I would have 1.000.000.xxx words. I want to pick one and when I want to pick another, previous picked words won't be in the result.

Is there any algorithm which is suitable for that?

PS: if codes would be suitable for MsSQL, C# would be better.

Edit: I want to show new and random word according to their frequency. For e.g: there are 4 words in table and the user wants to see more frequently word, 2 and 4. But 1st word is known and doesn't want to see it.I want to show more frequently 2nd and 4th but more rare 3rd.But in every shown I don't want to repetitive shown for the same word

Comment: Which database engine do you use?

Comment: Which db are you using? A SQL solution might be possible with knowledge of the db.

Comment: Do you need this separately for each user?

Comment: @svick, every user will be set their frequency.

Comment: What frequency? You didn't say anything about any frequencies until now.

Comment: :) yes I didn't say frequency. I want to show new and random word according to their frequency. For e.g: there are 4 words in table and the user wants to see more frequently word, 2 and 4. But 1st word is known and doesn't want to see it.I want to show more frequently 2nd and 4th but more rare 3rd.But in every shown I don't want to repetitive shown for the same word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a table `Words` like this with one word with a word for each row

```
create table Words 
(
  Word varchar(25) primary key,
  Freq int not null
)
```

you can get a random word using `order by newid()`.

```
select top 1 Word
from Words  
order by newid()
```

The frequency column is an `int` where every word have at least a 1 and words that is more frequent have higher values. To use `order by newid()` we have to create a table that contains duplicates for the words that has a higher freq value. That can be done using a [tally table](http://beyondrelational.com/puzzles/tsql/posts/english/1984/tsql-challenges-tally-table-script.aspx).

To keep track of the words you have already picked you can have another table.

```
create table PickedWords
(
  Word varchar(25) primary key
)
```

This is your statement to add the selected word to table `PickedWords` and use `output` clause to return the word to the client.

```
insert into PickedWords
output inserted.Word
select top 1 W.Word
from Words as W
  inner join tsqlc_Tally as T
    on W.Freq > T.N
where W.Word not in (select Word 
                     from PickedWords)
order by newid()
```

It takes 9 seconds on a really sad laptop with a 1.2 GHz processor for 1.000.000 words.

If you instead had a table with the words already duplicated instead of a frequency column so we can skip the tally table it takes 2 seconds to pick one word.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pick one word and if this word is repetited, discardit. Right?

Try this:

```
pick a word
search in a Map
if the word is in the Map
  repited word
else
  new word, insert in Map
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can do this by using ROWNUM:

```
SELECT WORD FROM (SELECT DISTINCT WORD FROM WORDS)
WHERE ROWNUM >= :START_INDEX AND ROWNUM <= :END_INDEX
```

In MySQL you can use LIMIT feature:

```
SELECT DISTINCT WORD FROM WORDS
LIMIT :NUMBER_OF_WORDS OFFSET :START_INDEX
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MS SQL, try out [RowNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

If you're developing C# application, try out `SQLDataAdapter` and `DataSet` with supported control in **.NET Framework**.

Comment: RowNumber ok but what will I do with the column which is generated from Row_Number() function?

Comment: the first time i read that topic, i assumed it's talking about paging (after that, i inserted some control support that work in **.NET FrameWork**). If it's what you're looking for, you can easyly search about it with **RowNumber()**.